# Not a JSON Object: null

Tags: java, json

I found a github that has an open source project, but it is broken. It tries to get the JSON off of https://api.randomuser.me/?nat=gb

I get the error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not a JSON Object: null

When I try to change it to an array, I get the error that it isn't any array. What gives?

```
 String json = readUrl(RANDGEN_URL);
        JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
        JsonObject firstNameObject = jsonParser.parse(json)
                .getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonArray("results").get(0)
                .getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonObject("name");
        String firstNameString = firstNameObject.get("first").getAsString();

        JsonObject lastNameObject = jsonParser.parse(json)
                .getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonArray("results").get(0)
                .getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonObject("name");
        String lastNameString = lastNameObject.get("last").getAsString();

        Random randMail = new Random();
        int setMail = randMail.nextInt(90) + 10;
        String mail = firstNameString + "." + lastNameString + "" + setMail + "@gmail.com";

        JsonObject usernames = jsonParser.parse(json)
                .getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonArray("results").get(0)
                .getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonObject("login");
        String user = usernames.get("username").getAsString();

        if (user.length() > 12) {
            Random randNum = new Random();
            int setNum = randNum.nextInt(90) + 10;
            user = user.substring(0, Math.min(user.length(), 10)) + setNum;
        }
```

Answer (score -2):

What library do you use?

```
// com.alibaba.fastjson

    String res = o.getJSONArray("results").getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("name").getString("title");
    System.out.println(res);

out:#  mr
```

Comment: Gson 

`System.out.println(jsonParser.parse(value).getAsJsonObject().get("results").getAsJsonArray().get(0).getAsJsonObject().get("name").getAsJsonObject().get("first").getAsString()); ` it works. I think in some cases you getting an empty array or requested key doesn't exists.  `getAsJsonArray().size()` & `getAsJsonObject().has("results")` etc... .